# Insert data into Visual Studio LocalDB in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, localdb

I have a Windows web application and have created a `.mdf` file in the `App_Data` folder and I am trying to insert data into the tables already created.

It is able to retrieve codes with a basic `SELECT *` statement, but I can't insert data, this is the code I have:

```
private void Update(string username)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"MYSQLCONNECTION");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    string bcd = "INSERT INTO NameList(name) VALUES (@paraUsername)";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(bcd, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paraUsername", username);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    list.Update();

    con.Close();
}
```

This code has worked for me in the past, but this time round it does not work. There is no error shown, but the data is not inserted into the table.

This is how I call the method in side my button_click method:

```
Update(tbName.text);
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: How you verify that the data is not inserted? Are you checking the right database?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'm certain that it's the right database, it's the only .mdf I have in this project. I have also inserted data manually into the Table and retrieving them doesn't seem to have any issue.

Comment: The code looks OK. It should insert the row in the table. Did you check in the database manually to verify if the row is inserted or not? What changes did you made after which it stopped working ?

Comment: This set of codes never worked with this project I'm working on currently, it was working perfectly on a previous project. Yes, I've checked the database manually, I did a try catch as well, there were no exceptions. It seems to me that everything went through however the issue lies with the Insert.

Comment: @marc_s my connection string is 
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AttDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: I did it this way as I want it to be a relative connectionstring that can be used across different PCs because I do this at school and home. If in the case that the attachdbfilename is the error, how should my connectionstring be constructed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a

```
AttachDbFileName=......
```

section in your connection string - then this is a known issue:

The whole *AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `YourDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.